# onClick function not calling a method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React project where a component SubmitButton is rendered when the property isSelectedNumber change its state to true. The component SubmitButton, which is a button you can click, will call a method when the button is clicked by using the onClick function and that will lead to the property isSubmitClicked change to true that the component NextButton will render.

The thing is that just the SubmitButton is rendered and when I click the button of the component SubmitButton it doesn't render the component NextButton.

This the part of the wrapper component where both components will be rendered if the conditions are true.

```
{this.state.isSelectedNumber ?  <SubmitButton  handleClickSumbmit={this.handleClickSumbmit}/>  : null}
 {this.state.isSubmitClicked ?   <NextButton /> : null}
```

This is the part of the SubmitButton Component where the onClick function should call the handleCliclkSubmit method to change the property state:

```
 <button type="button" onClick={this.props.handleClickSubmit}></button>
```

This is the handleClickSubmit method:

```
    handleClickSumbmit () {
      this.setState({
        isSubmitClicked: true
      });
  }
```

I was wondering if you have any idea what could be happening and how to solve it.

Comment: Did you hard-bind your `handleClickSumbmit` method in constructor? `this.handleClickSumbmit = this.handleClickSumbmit.bind(this);`

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but a more concise way to conditionally display components is {this.state.isSubmitClicked && <NextButton />}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typo error

Change

```
  <button type="button" onClick={this.props.handleClickSubmit}></button>
```

To

```
   <button type="button" onClick={this.props.handleClickSumbmit}></button>
```

Also the function name is not meaningful in your code. Change handleClickSumbmit to handleClickSubmit wherever you have handleClickSumbmit

Also since you are using regular function you have to bind it in constructor. I hope you already did that.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should check the calling of `handleClickSubmit`, where you call it as `handleClickSumbmit`, maybe that's where the problem lies.

Comment: It is a typo in either the declaration of the function, or when you call it from the button.